# How to convert a hash inside a string into a hash?

Tags: ruby

How can I convert data received from redis data which was stored as hash in string format back to hash?

Tried retriving from redis as string not able to convert to hash

The string looks like:

```
{"index"=>1, "isActive"=>true, "accountNumber"=>5137, "name"=>{"first"=>"Holder", "last"=>"Hanson"},}
```

Comment: You could convert it to json: `JSON.parse(string.gsub('=>', ':'))` or `hash = eval(string)` but eval is dangerous.

Comment: JSON won't work on complex objects like `Time`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save all Ruby hash parameters in a Redis hash and expect to get the attributes in similar way.
Before saving it in redis hash, ruby calls `to_s` on the attributes.

```
redis.hmset('foo', 'a', 'b', 'account', 1, 'date', Time.now)
redis.hgetall('foo') 
# => {"a"=>"b", "account"=>"1", "date"=>"2018-12-12 13:45:50 +0530"}
```

As you can see above, '1' is converted into the string and Time.now is converted from a `Time` **object** (`2018-12-12 13:45:42 +0530`) to the stringified `"2018-12-12 13:45:50 +0530"`

You can instead use the [**Marshal dump**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html) and set the ruby hash as redis key:

```
hash = {'a' => 'b', 'account' => 1, 'date' => Time.now }
# => {"a"=>"b", "account"=>1, "date"=>2018-12-12 13:47:25 +0530}
redis.set('foo', Marshal.dump(hash))
redis.get('foo')
# => "\u0004\b{\bI\"\u0006a\u0006:\u0006ETI\"\u0006b\u0006;\u0000TI\"\faccount\u0006;\u0000Ti\u0006I\"\tdate\u0006;\u0000TIu:\tTime\r\x88\xAD\u001D\x80-\xB8\x9CE\a:\voffseti\u0002XM:\tzoneI\"\bIST\u0006;\u0000F"
Marshal.load redis.get('foo')
#=> {"a"=>"b", "account"=>1, "date"=>2018-12-12 13:47:25 +0530}
```

Comment: helpful, so can we convert time donating string to time object to have it in hash?

Comment: @ray 'to have it in hash', are you referring to ruby hash or redis hash?

Comment: In ruby, I know, redis?

Comment: @ray to store it in redis hash, each value will have to be marshalled, and then each value has to marshal `load`ed back. Extremely cumbersome, unless someone writes an interface.